# PHP HTTP HEADER: how to keep/rebuild apache2's last-modified&ETag

Tags: php, http-headers, apache2

calling a .html on my website directly the header will be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 May 2013 14:53:30 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 24 Aug 2012 21:51:42 GMT
ETag: "1431a086-1e01-78e98c5498f1c"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 7681
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

now the request is  forwarded through a php script like

(- the use of the php script here is only to filter some words from the html before delivering it by a regex and to add a footer to every page)

and the header looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 May 2013 14:52:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

Question: How to keep "**Last-Modified**: ..." and "**ETag**: ..." ?

Thanks=)

Comment: Did you removed the semi-colon in the `; default_charset = "iso-8859-1"` line before changing the value & restarting the Apache server ?

Comment: Don't you got a `AddDefaultCharset  ISO-8859-1` in your httpd.conf file ? Even if this is only for text/plain or text/html file, your blank page might be seen as one

Comment: exactly, didn't think so since accessing the html files directly apache doesnt sent it but i just saw it, when you had said it was strange and must be somewhere else, in the apache vhost conf file of the part of the page delivering the html files through this php script - didnt expect it there!